# How to find out the number of time series stored in Prometheus LevelDB

Tags: monitoring, system-monitoring, prometheus

i'm responsible for maintaining the Prometheus servers in our company. The metrics however are provided by the teams.

Is there a way to find out the number of time series stored in the Prometheus datadase? We are using the default LevelDB data storage. 
I need these values to find out if i need to tweak the local storage settings of our Prometheus instances.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Did you manage to find a solution for the above? LevelDB is only used for indexes as far as I understand...

Comment: Unfortunately I didn't find a solution yet. Every hint is welcome.

Comment: I understand that Prometheus stores the time series on disk in one file per time series. Location is specified by the flag `storage.local.path`. Did you look into that?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

`prometheus_tsdb_head_series`

Just because I always forget and have to Google this, and this question is at the top.  As per [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55113528/prometheus-total-metric-count-and-prometheus-tsdb-head-series-results-differ) there will likely be a variance between `prometheus_tsdb_head_series` & `count({__name__=~".+"})` because of variations in what they consider "active", but unless you have a large variability in metric count, I'd recommend `prometheus_tsdb_head_series` because if you have a lot of metrics, it's a *lot* faster to query.

Comment: Note: If you use Prometheus in agent mode, you need to use metric called `prometheus_agent_active_series`

Answer (score 20):

How about `count({__name__=~".+"})`?

It does return number of time series in the database. I compared with amount of metrics currently exposed by each target by manual scrapping, and it matches it +/- 10%. I guess the difference is due to some targets that I had in the past and now they are offline.

Answer (score 8):

https://prometheusui.com:9090/status ---> Head Stats --> this will give you the entire status.

Answer (score 4):

After some more research and thanks to the comments of [David.B](https://serverfault.com/users/345696/david-b) i found a solution that 'works for me' ™

To find the number of time series stored by Prometheus i use this command in the `storage.local.path` folder :
`ls -l {{0..9},{a..f}}{{0..9},{a..f}} | grep -E "*.db$" | wc -l`

In addition in found some metrics in the [prometheus documentation](https://prometheus.io/docs/operating/storage/#helpful-metrics) that might help when dealing with memory problems/optimization.

This might not be the most sophisticated way but it gave me the numbers i was looking for.

Answer (score 1):

Go to this URL:

https://YOUR-PROMETHEUS-UI:9090/tsdb-status

[image]

OR Query this:

`prometheus_tsdb_head_series`

OR query this:

`count({__name__=~".+"}`

OR you can also count files in `storage.local.path` with `ls -l {{0..9},{a..f}}{{0..9},{a..f}} | grep -E "*.db$" | wc -l` I've not tested this one.

Answer (score 0):

You could try ({**name**=~".+"}) on the prometheus console to get the total time series

Comment: I tried this in the first place. Unfortunately `count({name=~".+"})` gives me a number that is smaller than the number given by `prometheus_local_storage_memory_series`.
In my case this is 3k from `count` and 130k from `prometheus_local_storage_memory_series`. I would expect that the number of time series in memory is equal or smaller than the total number of time series and not the other way round. The version from above (`ls -l {{0..9},{a..f}}{{0..9},{a..f}} | grep -E "*.db$" | wc -l`) tells me i have 527k time series.

Comment: `count({__name__=~".+"})` will give you the number you are looking for.